# Entity Framework .Net Core using VS2019 Community on Mac OS don't works

Tags: c#, entity-framework, migration

I try to use EF core 3.1.0, could you see above:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbL9X.png)

I created a DBContext class:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using SGC.ApplicationCore.Entity;

namespace SGC.Infrastructure.Data
{
public class ClienteContext:DbContext
{

    public ClienteContext(DbContextOptions<ClienteContext> options):base(options)
    {        }


    public DbSet<Cliente> Clientes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Contato> Contatos { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Cliente>().ToTable("Cliente");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Contato>().ToTable("Contato");
    }
}
```

And I inserted this code in UI project Startup.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting; 
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using SGC.Infrastructure.Data;

namespace SGC.UI.Web
{
public class Startup
{ 

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;

    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }


    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();


        services.AddDbContext<ClienteContext>(c => c.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
}
```

And the code of Program.cs class is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace SGC.UI.Web
{
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
}
```

When I try to run de Migrations command, it throw this exception:

Unable to create an object of type 'ClienteContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

If I change the constructor of ClienteContext.cs to a parameterless constructor the migrations command works.

migration commands:

> dotnet ef migrations add Inicial

Comment: Could you add this nuget to your asp.net core app and try again -> https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design/

Comment: This is covered in detail here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dbcontext-creation

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft he already checked the link you provided but was not helpful, it is included in the question.

Comment: Since you updated Net make sure you do a clean build of both the Nuget and then the c# project.  The compiler dependencies do not recognize the change in Net and may not work and you project will not work with object code that is a mixture of different versions of Net.

Comment: @panoskarajohn I included the Design package in SGC.UI.Web application, and the same exception is thrown. P.S: I executed the migrations commands from SGC.Infrastructure project folder. –

Comment: @jdweng - I cleaned the solution and restored Nuget packages, after I tried to run migrations command and the same exceptions was thrown.

Comment: @WilliamFernandesMagalhães Inside which dotnet project you run the migration(try with your asp.net core). Your code seems correct. I am not even sure what could be wrong.

Comment: I would ask question at following : https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-core-3-1/

Comment: @panoskarajohn I tried to do what you said. The exception throw was:

Your target project 'SGC.UI.Web' doesn't match your migrations assembly 'SGC.Infrastructure'. Either change your target project or change your migrations assembly.
Change your migrations assembly by using DbContextOptionsBuilder. E.g. options.UseSqlServer(connection, b => b.MigrationsAssembly("SGC.UI.Web")). By default, the migrations assembly is the assembly containing the DbContext.

Comment: @panoskarajohn to be continued:
Change your target project to the migrations project by using the Package Manager Console's Default project drop-down list, or by executing "dotnet ef" from the directory containing the migrations project.

Comment: @jdweng Already update VS and all tools to last release. The same problem yet.